# Sharepoint User Login Report

Tags: sharepoint-designer

How to pull user login report/hit count (including user names) from SharePoint websites?
(Besides Audit Reports & Popularity Usage report)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to use the IIS logs to gather this information, then I would use PowerBI to make reports from the IIS logs.  There are also third party analytics tools that will accomplish this.